# Is it true that who never marries won't have a share in Olam HaBa?

Tags: zohar

If I am not mistaken, Rav P.S. Berg ( I know he is not a good source according to Jewish authorities) said in his book "The Essential Zohar" that if someone didn't get married during his lifetime, he won't have a share in Olam Haba.

In case that's true, is the same rule apply to gentiles ?

P.S: I , again, know that his work and university is not trusted among Jewish authority.

Comment: כל ישראל יש להם חלק לעולם הבא

Comment: @Daniel I don't speak Hebrew, I wish I do but I don't

Comment: It's a quote from the Mishnah. It means "All Israel has a portion of the World to Come." It's not necessarily meant to be taken as literally applicable all of the time, though.

Comment: @Daniel though Rabbi Yosef Mizrachi in a youtube video said that some Israelites/Jews lost their portions in the world like a Northern Israeli King I forgot his name, and a Torah scholar (maybe the father or grandfather of Bathsheba ) who kept saying bad things about King David, etc....

Comment: @DoubleAA, this is not a duplicate of that. The other asks whether it's acceptable to not marry. This asks whether someone who doesn't marry has a share in _olam haba_. Conceivably, it's not acceptable to not marry (as indeed the answer there indicates), but the question of whether the person who acts unacceptably has a share in _olam haba_ remains open.